# Compatibility issue with Python 3.10 + aiohttp and .NET 4.X

Tags: python, macos

I have a Python 3.10 aiohttp server running on a Mac computer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ssl
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain('server.cert', 'server.key')

    app = web.Application()
    # app.router.add_route('*', '/{tail:.*}', root_handler)

    async def start_site(app, address, port):
        runner = web.AppRunner(app)
        await runner.setup()

        site = web.TCPSite(runner, address, port, ssl_context = ssl_context)
        await site.start()

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(start_site(app, '0.0.0.0', '8443'))
    loop.run_forever()
```

And a .NET 4.5 client on Windows Server 2012 R2 Virtual Machine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://172.16.177.1:8443/");
            request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I start the client, Python Server closes the connection immediately after CLIENT HELLO, and the client raised an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Then I did more tests to figure out whether the problem is from client side or server side:

1. Python 3.10 + Ubuntu 22.04: works fine
2. Homebrew Python 3.9 + Mac: works fine

So clearly the problem is from `homebrew python 3.10`.
How can I figure out what's wrong with homebrew Python 3.10?

Comment: You didn't describe a problem yet - no error messages, no exceptions. .NET Framework 4.5 doesn't run on Mac and isn't supported any more. The earliest supported version is 4.6.2. Windows 8 is out of support as well, the earliest supported version is Windows 10. Only .NET Core runs on Mac.  The code you posted shows you encountered SSL certificate problems and tried to ignore them instead of fixing them

Comment: Instead of disabling TLS, trust the same development certificate on both machines. On the other hand, right now you're testing the bugs in unsupported runtime and OS versions, which probably need patching too. Use .NET Core on Mac instead and use the HttpClient class to call the service. All this code can be replaced with `var responseString=await client.GetStringAsync(url);`. Since both server and client code run on the same machine, they both trust the same certificates

Comment: That's a TLS error. The solution is to stop using obsolete .NET and Windows versions. In the last 6 years almost all services moved to TLS 1.1 or TLS1.2 as a minimum. Since 2016 both web services *and operating systems* started deprecating older TLS versions. Older OSs require patching to support TLS1.2 by default. .NET Framework 4.6.2 and later will use the best available TLS version found on the OS, whether it's TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3. With older versions you had to manually specify the TLS version and 4.5. didn't even have a constant for this

Comment: You get this error because [Python 3.10 removed support for TLS1.1](https://bugs.python.org/issue43998), as it should.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I think it means `Default to TLS 1.2`, not to remove every cipher below it right? Also, if it's what you said, why would the Python 3.10 on Ubuntu server work then ...

Comment: The real question is, why are you trying to use obsolete .NET and Windows versions? That link says that TLS1.1 will be disabled outright. `Python should no longer enable TLS 1.1 by default` that means it's off by default but you can re-enable it. Which you *shouldn't* do. If you run [Windows 8.1 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#bkmk_winhttp) TLS 1.2 is available by default. But only .NET Framework 4.6.2 will use it without hard-coding it

Comment: Why not [install .NET Core on Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos) and use a modern runtime?